# listview 1 activites used to open listview 2 activites

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget, android-listview

i want listview1 to open some activities defined in my package and on those activites i have redefined a new listview2 activity.

i have tried to code for same.
please have a look at the code to understand the problem.

```
public class ABC extends ListActivity{

String classNames[] = {"A","B","C"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classNames));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = classNames[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.lab.example."+openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

on the above source code a,b,c classes can be seen in the listview. but when i click on A, nothing happens.

i want to know 
     `@Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>          (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classNames));
     }`

How could i add a custom layout above

while for
  Class A:-

```
public class A extends ListActivity{

String classNames[] = {"x1","x2","x3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = classNames[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.lab.example."+openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

on the above source code x1,x2,x3 class activites are working for A only
```

while X1:-

```
public class X1 extends Activity {
// List view
private ListView lv;
// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Listview Data
    String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.X1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view11);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch11);
    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, R.id.route, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);      
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            X1.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}
```

}

Manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lab.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.lab.example.MainActivitypage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.lab.example.Menu" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.ABC" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.A" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.B" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.C" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.X1" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.X2" />
   <activity android:name="com.lab.example.X3" />
```

Errors shown in log cat:-

the log is full of this error nothing else as i am new to android cant understand this:-

```
03-14 23:16:55.970: E/PGA(3459): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
03-14 22:32:23.810: E/InputDispatcher(1304): channel 'b466cb20      com.lab.example/com.lab.example.ABC (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 
03-14 22:34:45.480: E/ALSALib(1293): external/alsa-lib/src/confmisc.c:136:    (snd_config_get_bool) Invalid type for nonblock
```

i want when i click A->X1 to start activity.
if i am not clear then please mention in below comment.
any sort of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "but when i click on A, nothing happens." Are these Activities in your Manifest? (I have never tried to fetch a class reference like that...)

Comment: yes i have defined them in my manifest.

Comment: if you think this may be the new topic of research then please do vote.

Comment: @dex Sorry, What is your requirement First you have a listview contains classess A,B,C and then when you click A, it will open listView with X1,X2,X3 as list items, and then when click on X1 it should open X1 activity right..?

Comment: @pragnani yes you got it right...

Comment: @dex But what is your problem, Where is your code failed, Where is the log cat response..

Comment: @pragnani the code failed at the first step itself, did not moved from class A to class X1 it did not responded on the click.

Comment: It should work. Please click [edit] to post your manifest and all of the LogCat errors.

Comment: Is it because you don't have `@Override` before your `onListItemClick()` methods?

Comment: just put @Override before `onListItemClick`  and also use Log to check row click is happening or not

Comment: the log is full of this two error
03-14 22:32:23.810: E/InputDispatcher(1304): channel 'b466cb20 com.lab.example/com.lab.example.ABC (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

03-14 22:34:45.480: E/ALSALib(1293): external/alsa-lib/src/confmisc.c:136:(snd_config_get_bool) Invalid type for nonblock

Comment: @sam overriding did not worked for me..

and i am unable to copy the log..

Comment: @dex : *overriding did not worked for me* means ? as i told u put log inside onListItemClick in ABC Activity and check logcat. ListView row click happening or not

Comment: Click [edit] below your question and put the errors in there.

Comment: can u guys try this concept at your end with a dummy project and check weather this concept is valid or not.

if any of you succeed let all of us know the solution and the mistake.

Comment: Your approach is different, but I tried it and it should work. I recommend rebooting your computer and device(s), I have never seen that error before and have no idea what causes it...

Comment: @sam i rebooted my computer too but it did not worked for me.
anybody has a diiferent suggetion then please help me.

Comment: @all can u please suggest me how to add a custom layout in my ABC

Answer (score 1):

change `classNames` Array of `A`   `ListActivity` as :

```
String classNames[] = {"X1","X2","X3"};
```

because you are declaring Activities in AndroidManifest.xml  using X1,X2 and X3 class name

Comment: @Sam : i found this additional issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.lab.example", "com.lab.example." + openClass);
startActivity(intent);
```